# Is there a Box with Title in Material UI

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, fieldset

Is there a way to create a Box or a Paper with a title on top like this screenshot : [image]

I'm talking about the top lefty title portion. I tried using a Box or a Paper component but it doesn't seem like the option is there.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change a `Box`'s underlying element to a `fieldset` and add a `legend` element as a child of the MUI `Box`, but you'll probably want to apply a little styling to it as MUI does not offer styled versions of `fieldset`/`legend`.

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

const FieldsetExample = () => {
  return (
    <Box component="fieldset">
      <legend>Jean-François H</legend>
      Box content goes here.
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Renders:
[image: Rendered fieldset code]

**Working CodeSandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-booth-09dwu7?file=/demo.js

**Documentation References:**
[MUI Docs - `Box` API props (see `component`)](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/box/#props)
[MDN Docs - `<fieldset>`: The Field Set element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)

Comment: FYI This should work for MUI 4 as well (you didn't specify a version) with just a change of the imports.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for that. It's exactly what I was looking for. How the heck did you figure that out? I've been looking for the past day for that kind of information on MUI docs!

Comment: Haha I work with the Box `component` prop a lot (for accessibility), and I just happened to recognize the `fieldset` element from your picture. Glad I could help! :D